# Group strings that have the same words but in a different order

Tags: r, string, grouping

I have an example concatenated text field (please see sample data below) that is created from two or three different fields, however there is no guarantee that the order of the words will be the same. I would like to create a new dataset where fields with the same words, regardless of order, are collapsed. However, since I do not know in advance what words will be concatenated together, the code will have to recognize that all words in both strings match.

Code for example data:

```
var1<-c("BLUE|RED","RED|BLUE","WHITE|BLACK|ORANGE","BLACK|WHITE|ORANGE")
freq<-c(1,1,1,1)
have<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,freq))
```

Have:

```
var1                 freq
BLUE|RED              1
RED|BLUE              1
WHITE|BLACK|ORANGE    1
BLACK|WHITE|ORANGE    1
```

How can I collapse the data into what I want below?

```
color               freq
BLUE|RED              2
WHITE|BLACK|ORANGE    2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data.frame(table(sapply(strsplit(have$var1, '\\|'), 
             function(x)paste(sort(x), collapse = '|'))))

                Var1 Freq
1 BLACK|ORANGE|WHITE    2
2           BLUE|RED    2
```

In the world of piping: R > 4.0

```
have$var1 |>
  strsplit('\\|')|>
  sapply(\(x)paste0(sort(x), collapse = "|"))|>
  table()|>
  data.frame()
```

Comment: Thank you, follow-up question - if the existing frequency of, say, "BLUE|RED" is more than one, how do I add instances of "RED|BLUE" onto the existing total? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

have %>% 
  group_by(id=row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(var1) %>% 
  arrange(var1, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = paste(var1, collapse = "|")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  count(var1, name = "freq")
```

```
  var1                freq
  <chr>              <int>
1 BLACK|ORANGE|WHITE     2
2 BLUE|RED               2
```